# What to do with a question where I asked why my code is wrong, after I figured out that the issue wasn't related to the code?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50427701/displaying-a-meta-description-on-a-sites-homepage) asking for help in figuring out why my code wasn't working.

It turns out that the code that I used was valid, and the issue was with the caching on my site (so I kept seeing an older version of the website, before the relevant changes were implemented).

Since the question already drew two upvotes and since I believe that the code itself could be helpful to others in my situation, I'm not sure what to do now.

My options as I see them are:

1. Delete the question.
2. Keep the question as is, and add an edit which explains the issue.
3. Add an answer which explains that the issue was with the caching, and that the code itself is valid.
4. Edit the question so that it asks for what is the relevant code to use in my situation, and then add the relevant code in an answer.

None of these solutions look optimal to me. (1) looks like a waste, (2) is problematic since the question won't have an answer, (3) will involve an answer that is unrelated to coding, and (4) will involve modifying the original question in a way that changes it significantly. However, all things considered, (4) seems like the best option to me.

Comment: There's probably a duplicate you could mark it....caching is a common issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question has no answer. As such, you can edit it as heavily as you want without making any other content obsolete or invalid (within reason).

Edit your question with all relevant details, remove the unnecessary ones, then self-answer and accept your own answer in two days.

You properly identified the right option.

Comment: _"Your question has no answer."_ That's to say, _"Nobody has posted an answer to your question yet..."_