# What should I do if the issue I asked about was actually not the actual issue?

Tags: discussion, questions, xy-problem

I had an issue with my code and decided to ask someone for help. With the help of other users (who wrote valid answers to my original question), I found out the issue was being caused by another, underlying, issue. The answer for the underlying issue was given by one of the answers' authors in a comment.

The original question, though, is a valid one, and both answers are valid answers for it.

Since it has at least 2 answers, I believe I can't have it closed, right (as per [What to do with a question where I asked why my code is wrong, after I figured out that the issue wasn't related to the code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368268/what-to-do-with-a-question-where-i-asked-why-my-code-is-wrong-after-i-figured-o))? Also, the question has a single upvote. I'm not sure what course of action I should take now. Should I just flag it for a moderator to close it?

Comment: A bit related: [What should I do when the OP asks the wrong question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322991)

Comment: *"Since it has at least 2 answers, I believe I can't have it closed"* Wrong, any question can be closed; whether it has 0, 1, or 100 answers, and regardless of how well received those posts are.

Comment: "The original question, though, is a valid one, and both answers are valid answers for it." Then you don't need to do any thing. If the question is valid, it doesn't matter whether it was actually the issue you had.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Nope - just ask a new question.  Your original question is still "good", and you can use that as a jumping-off point for your next question.

As long as you provide copious amounts of detail as to why the question you're asking now isn't the same as the one you asked before, you'll probably be just fine.

Comment: What about the help I got from the comments from the person answering? They did help me with the underlying issue (in fact they solved the whole issue!). I'm sorry if this is a common/stupid question, I just want to follow the rules.

Comment: Ask a *separate* question.  If you have a new question, you ask a new question.  Don't draw out conversations in comments or edit your existing question since both actions invalidate *that* question (and are hallmarks of someone trying to circumvent some kind of rate limit).

Comment: Understood. Should I direct the previous answerer to the new question so they can post their answer there as well, or mention their name at all?

Comment: You could just provide the answer in the new question yourself in the form of a Community Wiki, and be sure to cite the person you got the answer from (in the form of both their name and the link to the comment which helped you).  No need to ask others to do what you can take action on yourself.

Comment: If it helps, think "what would be useful to lurkers?". Lurkers who came across your original question post might not have the same underlying issue that you have. So they might appreciate the other answers. But they might have the same underlying issue, so they will appreciate the answer you found useful, and a link to your new question.